# PHP Apache - How do I create a secure working directory, invisible to web

Tags: php, security

I have created a PHP script that takes a large html file and, using DOMDocument, chops it up into smaller files.  To save on script memory and without having to use a DB, I've done this sequentially and saved them as hundreds of html files.  My question is, how do I make sure these files cannot be visible to the outside world, but still retain the ability to use them as resources for future processing (piece together various files and display them on a page)?

I'm using Amazon EC2 - Centos 6/Apache.

Thank you!

Comment: You can also use SQLite if you don't want to deal with thousands of files or a database with a server/client model. It's built into PHP by default (with PDO), so just start using it.

Comment: Thank you Xeoncross.  I will definitely convert my system to SQLite for the 2.0 version.  For now, Madara Uchina's solution worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them on a directory which isn't a subdirectory of your web root directory (i.e. the publicly opened directory).

Another possible approach (if you are using Apache), is to use an `.htaccess` file to `Deny from all` in a directory.

Comment: @JamesHuckabone: Yes, In both approaches, PHP and Apache still have access to those directories.

Comment: Uchina - I did that and restarted the web server, but I can still see the directory contents.  Do I need to initialize some ini entry to use .htaccess?

Comment: Sorry to ask an easy one, I figured it out.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

By far the best approach is to store them outside the document root (perhaps one level below).

Otherwise, perhaps at a future point, your settings, `.htaccess` file `httpd.conf` or other elements may change and reveal the directory contents.

Storing them outside the docroot means they will **never** become visible.